# Center mouse on displays other than the primary

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, powershell, mouse

I've got a sales demo room with multiple displays(4 to be exact) Currently connected to separate machines, all with separate keyboards and mice.  From a management standpoint this is a nightmare i want to connection these displays all to a single machine with an nvidia p4000.  The sales guys use each display to showcase a different software solution/portal to our product.  I've seen a lot of solutions on how to center a mouse in the primary screen,  i'm hoping someone can help me with the script to center the mouse in each of these displays.  Unfortunately our sales guys don't always work in order and don't always go through all four products.  so the ideal is sale F1 centers on the left left display,  F2 middle left display, and so on to f4 being right right.

I've been working with a base powershell script and a keyboard short cut, sturggling to find what additional monitors are called.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | out-null
$bounds = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds
$center = $bounds.Location
$center.X += $bounds.Width / 2
$center.Y += $bounds.Height / 2
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = $center
```

As a bonus,  i'd love to make the four monitors there own zones, ie you can't scroll between them, thus never losing the mouse someplace out in space.  I feel like there must be a software solution for this but i'm either googling the wrong thing or it doesn't exist.

any help would be fantastic.

Comment: May want to look into AutoHotKey. It can be scripted to do what you want here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320139/snap-mouse-cursor-to-center-of-screen . Using powershell to take keystrokes is a but more difficult to work because of the way it needs to be the active window when looking for keystrokes. There are ways to get around this, but AHK is much easier for what you are looking to do.

Comment: also an even easier solution is to use nircmd because it has the `setcursor x y` command. You can just math out your other monitors. If they are all standard 1080p, then your 4 different batches would be `setcursor 960 540` for monitor 1, `setcursor 2880 540` for monitor 2, `setcursor 4800 540` for monitor 3, and `setcursor 6720 540` for monitor 4 assuming they are all next to each other. Each one of these would be its own batch and then assigned to an F key.